# How to customize Window in JFXtras Labs 8.0?

Tags: javafx, jfxtras

I can change icons(close,minimize) background, but i don't know how to change icon size and tittle bar size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you change the font size of the header, then the change is proportional to the size of icons and the titlebar itself.

css file:

```
.custom-window-titlebar {
    -fx-font: Tahoma;
    -fx-font-size: 60px;
    -fx-fill: rgba(255,255,255,50);
    -fx-alignment: center;
    }
```

and set style class:

```
Window window = new Window("My MDI Window");
window.setPrefSize(1760, 770);
window.setTitleBarStyleClass("custom-window-titlebar");
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me, has something changed in the last year?  I am using this exact code and the font size seems to be the same as before.